# Inherit image width from font

Tags: css, image, inheritance, width, font-awesome

I'm in a predicament which has meant I've had to co-use images and FontAwesome icons. My problem is that, naturally, font sizes change. Is it possible to inherit the image size from the icon sizes?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Icon Fonts aren't images they are text characters and are always based on font-size. What images are you referring to?

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is that I have to use both the font icon and an image side-by-side but I need the image to mimic the size of the font. So for example `<i class="icon icon-eye"></i><img src="/_System/img/star.png" style="min-width:inherit;"/>`

Comment: No...inheritance works from parent to child..not between siblings (hence *"inheritance"*). You would have to explicity set the sizes to be the same in the css.

Comment: Hmm, I was afraid of that. Okay, no problem. Thanks for the info :)

Comment: You can use relative units, i.e. `em`, for the height or width of images. Is that not working?

Comment: I just noticed this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5485341/css-div-width-depending-on-image-size-above?rq=1  I think it should be possible to apply that answer to your problem as well...