# Make paragraph the same width as the image

Tags: css, responsive

I am trying to make p tag the same width as the image.

```
<a class="preview-holder" href="#" target="_blank">
  <div class='preview'>
    <img src="http://s31.postimg.org/9c62tqc63/Carpet_Tree_of_Life.jpg" alt="" />
    <p>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra</p>
  </div>
</a>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2hum47n0/2/

I looks well if the image is wider than the amount of text but not otherwise.

I dont need to use p, I can use span, or change markup a little if necessary.

Is it possible?

Note that preview cannot have fixed width!

Comment: The problem is when the width grows, the height grows too, so there are no easy solution for this: https://jsfiddle.net/2hum47n0/3/

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5485341/css-div-width-depending-on-image-size-above

Comment: If you don't want a fixed width to preview, give width with %

Comment: Do you really need two containers (`a` and `div`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put some css on preview holder:

```
.preview-holder {
  display: block;
  max-width: 1px;
}
```

[Demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2hum47n0/11/)

Answer (score 1):

Let try this

**HTML**

```
<a class="preview-holder" href="#" target="_blank">
  <div class='preview'>
  <div class="inner">
    <img src="http://s31.postimg.org/9c62tqc63/Carpet_Tree_of_Life.jpg" alt="" />
    <p>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.preview {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 1%;
  display:table;
}
.preview .inner {height: auto; overflow: hidden}
.preview img {
  display: block;
}

.preview p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  color: #333;
}

.preview-hover {
  background-color: #FC5A5A;
}
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/2hum47n0/8/)**

How it works:
You need to have a surrounding div that has a minimal width (1%), and make it display as a table; then the inner div (corresponding to the "inner") should have an auto height and hidden overflow, this is needed to "force" it to strech the div's width + height

Comment: `float: left` is totally unnecessary here. Avoid floats to make this things

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude that OP code (see his demo), i not sure what it do to his site so i not remove it

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery:

http://jsfiddle.net/n6DAu/2608/

```
$('.preview').width($('#img').width());
```

Comment: Note that preview cannot have fixed width!

Answer (score 0):

```css
.preview {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;
}

.preview .image-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  
}

.preview .image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}
.preview .text {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<a class="preview-holder" href="#" target="_blank">
  <div class='preview'>
    <div class="image-wrapper">
      <div class="image" style="background-image: url(http://s31.postimg.org/9c62tqc63/Carpet_Tree_of_Life.jpg;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <p>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

try this and let me know if there will be any problem. please check cross-browser and report if there is any problem.